# What is meant by fine-tuning of neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

In many research articles on neural network, I read the term "fine-tuning". As far as I understood, this is not a selection of parameters. Could someone please explain what it exactly means?

Answer (score 33):

Finetuning means taking weights of a trained neural network and use it as initialization for a new model being trained on data from the same domain (often e.g. images). It is used to:

1. speed up the training
2. overcome small dataset size

There are various strategies, such as training the whole initialized network or "freezing" some of the pre-trained weights (usually whole layers). The article [A Comprehensive guide to Fine-tuning Deep Learning Models in Keras](https://flyyufelix.github.io/2016/10/03/fine-tuning-in-keras-part1.html) provides a good insight into this. Also have a look at the following threads:

- [Fine Tuning vs Joint Training vs Feature Extraction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255364/fine-tuning-vs-joint-training-vs-feature-extraction)
- [CNN: ReTraining and Fine Tuning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278977/cnn-retraining-and-fine-tuning)